# Incorrect public IP Address after upgrading AWS Lightsail (Plesk) snapshot to another Lightsail Plesk instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, plesk, amazon-lightsail, static-ip-address

I am trying to upgrade my hosting from the 1GB RAM to the 2GB RAM instance from an existing Plesk Lightsail snapshot to another Plesk instance. I was able to create a larger instance and load the snapshot successfully. I was able to access the files via FTP and the databases were all present as expected. However, when I logged into Plesk via {NewStaticIP}:8443/ (using the same credentials as I did with my old instance), I was able to login but the IP address shown was still the old one.

The mistake I made was that for my old instance, I had not assigned a static IP and was using the default public IP provided by Lightsail. If I had defined a static IP to the old one, it would have been easy. I would detach the static IP from the old and attach it to the new and there would be no need to make any change in the DNS records even.

However now, even if I change the A record to point to the new Static IP I've assigned to the new instance (I use Cloudflare), it propagates instantly but shows me a "Web server is down" (Cloudflare error 521). This is confusing me because the server has been set up and I can access it via FTP. Ports 80, 443, 8443, 8447, 21, 22 are all open as well.

When I try to access the website using the static IP, it shows an error that the server refused to connect.

In addition, via Plesk Tools, I was able to change the IP address shown for that server but I also read that it's not the best way to change the address of the server so not sure if this helps or not.

Any help regarding this would be much appreciated. Thank you...

Comment: Hmm, if connecting to the static IP directly won't work there must be a configuration error. Are you sure the webserver is listening on the proper ip? (ie. your static ip or 0.0.0.0)

Comment: On running the following command via SSH it shows the new static IP address:
curl ifconfig.me

Comment: Would it be alright to assign a new static IP to my old instance, take a snapshot, create a new larger instance based on the new snapshot, and then assign the new instance with that same static IP?

My only concern is that I do not want to lose any data, files or server config of my old instance as I am still using that (for the time being).